# Why gdb needs a memory map of ram and rom of the target for debugging

Tags: memory, memory-management, gdb, gdbserver

please can some one guide me why gdb needs a memory map of RAM and ROM of the target for debugging.

If we enable verbose console in gdb then we can see some traces clearly showing:
 and also fro the ROM.

Is this memory used for code placement or for some other purpose.....please clarify me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about memory map defined with gdb's mem command, it's because gdb needs to know how to treat memory.

By default it assumes it can write to all of memory and cache all of it.

This is important for different reasons, one most common scenario being user trying to set a breakpoint. By default "software" breakpoints are used, which requires gdb to replace original instruction at address where breakpoint is set with special breakpoint instruction. If memory is read-only it can not do that, and has to use hardware breakpoints, which are limited in number or might even not be available. Having memory regions defined relieves user for having to manually select most appropriate breakpoint instruction (break/hbreak) manually, as gdb will automatically use hardware breakpoints in read-only regions.

Details are explained in [this chapter of GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory-Region-Attributes.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info...
Actually I am using an eclipse based IDE for debugging. The board configuration file for my target provided by the IDE specifies the size of RAM as 256KB while the data sheet for sabre lite shows that it has 1 GB of memory?

Comment: Then probably initialization code relies on board having only 256kB of memory and you will not be able to use more without issues (stack will is commonly located at top of memory and heap can also extend only to the top)... But do provide more details in question. What this configuration file defines depends on IDE used.